# Relacionamento 1-1 e referência circular

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Estou realizando um teste bem simples, onde tenho duas entidades com um relacionamento de 1-1 entre elas:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Job Job { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Mapeamento entre ambas:

```
public class UserMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(u => u.Id);
        builder.HasOne(u => u.Job).WithOne(j => j.User);
    }
}

public class JobMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Job>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Job> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(j => j.Id);
        builder.Property(j => j.Title).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Ao retornar a lista de usuários sem incluir os Jobs dos  mesmos, tenho sucesso.

Porém, ao realizar um Include, a lista de Jobs é retornada, porém causando uma referência circular:

```
var users = _context.Users.Include(u => u.Job).ToList();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1. Para que a referência circular não ocorra, é necessário que eu remova UserId da entidade Job? Pois não faz sentido para mim que para retornar todos os usuários com seus Jobs eu primeiro precise consultar os Jobs e incluir os Users.
   Gostaria de poder consultar os users e jobs, e caso fosse necessário, realizar um include em qualquer um deles.
2. Se eu adicionar suporte ao NewtonsoftJson no Startup, há uma configuração para que ele ignore as referências circulares ao serializar o conteúdo para JSON. É recomendado deixar a consulta do jeito que está e simplesmente utilizar essa opção do Newtonsoft para contornar o problema?

Comment: `public virtual User User { get; set; }`

Comment: Colocar a propriedade como virtual não muda o resultado da consulta. Além de que eu estou realizando um include manualmente.

Comment: Esse comportamento deve estar relacionado ao que chamamos de **Lazy Loading** no Entity Framework. Se for o caso, entenda os prós e contras de desativá-lo.
`Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`
[Entity Framework - Lazy Loading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_lazy_loading.htm#:~:text=Lazy%20loading%20is%20the%20process,you%20specifically%20request%20for%20it.)